# How can I deploy a Azure Function with multiple Names with the Maven plugin?

Tags: java, azure, maven

Is there a straightforward way to publish a function I build to multiple named instances? IE, I want to build my function, then deploy it to FunctionUserA, FunctionUserB, etc. I know I can use the Azure CLI to do this, but was hoping it could all be done through maven.

Answer (score 1):

When you create Azure Function by using `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.microsoft.azure -DarchetypeArtifactId=azure-functions-archetype -DjavaVersion=8`, the generated pom.xml should have a property `functionAppName` like below which is referred when deploying via maven (`mvn azure-functions:deploy`).
[image]
Update it to make it a placeholder like:

```
<!-- function app name -->
<appName>${functionAppNameToDeploy}</appName>
<!-- function app resource group -->
<resourceGroup>${resourceGroupToDeploy}</resourceGroup>
```

Then you can pass the `functionAppName` argument while running deploy command (note 'D' prefix is required). Likewise you can pass any custom arguments if required to mvn command in general.

```
mvn azure-functions:deploy -DfunctionAppNameToDeploy=FunctionUserA -DresourceGroupToDeploy=MyResourceGroup
mvn azure-functions:deploy -DfunctionAppNameToDeploy=FunctionUserB -DresourceGroupToDeploy=MyResourceGroup
```

But AFAIK you cannot do it to deploy to multiple at one shot AFAIK. Need to run the above with different function app names separately.

Comment: Thanks! Right now I have to also do a maven package -DfunctionAppName=xyz or the deploy fails. It fails because it tries to find the deploy target by appName. Anyways, thank you.

Comment: Sorry there slight problem with naming in my last answer. Can you check the updated answer?